# iOS - how to get twitter OAuthtoken with username and password

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to iPhone and i am just trying to create an app that has a login screen which accept twitter username and password,

But i don't know how to get the Oauthtoken

i got some help to call this url

`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token`

but don't know what to send the values in these parameters

`oauth_consumer_key,  oauth_consumer_secret, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method.`

or any other method to get Oauthtoken from twitter

Thanks, in Advance.

Comment: check this link
 http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Answer (score 2):

1 - Create an application on Twitter web site https://dev.twitter.com/apps you will be given a "consumer key" and a "consumer secret".

2 - Add the STTwitter library into your project https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

3 - The following code will login and print the "access token" and "access token secret" as you requested:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = 
    [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerName:@"MyApp"
                                      consumerKey:@"BJaKx0V7hdDafkFXK4P08g"
                                   consumerSecret:@"DRSZf2Bc9Qgl0HDE7gGjzXYuQPkwk9gsAYgENFnWJs"
                                         username:@"nst021"
                                         password:@"xxxxxxxx"];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

    NSLog(@"-- access granted for %@", username);
    NSLog(@"-- oauthAccessToken %@", twitter.oauthAccessToken);
    NSLog(@"-- oauthAccessTokenSecret %@", twitter.oauthAccessTokenSecret);
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-- error %@", error);
}];
```

4 - You can then retrieve the timeline this way:

```
[twitter getHomeTimelineSinceID:nil count:@"20" successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
    // ...
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you would need a twitter account.Sign in to https://dev.twitter.com/apps to create a new applications and thus you will have oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret keys.

Your twitter keys should be similar to these

Consumer key :

```
Cyn74Fsa8fMn7lvEcnWK8A
```

Consumer secret :

```
sUeiThf1tEPV3od9jKBAuN8LdmDsLnAaH5RmG4ZWFE
```

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"]];[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"oauth_consumer_key = Cyn74Fsa8fMn7lvEcnWK8A&oauth_consumer_secret = sUeiThf1tEPV3od9jKBAuN8LdmDsLnAaH5RmG4ZWFE&oauth_version = 1.0&x_auth_mode = client_auth&x_auth_password = mypassword&x_auth_username = myusername";
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

But it reponse null

Comment: Try using this urlString https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token instead of api.twitter.com

Comment: still it's responding null


 NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    

    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
  
    NSError* error;
    
    NSDictionary *rootObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:response1 //1
                                options:kNilOptions
                                error:&error];